# How to build a cheap adjustable stand

Tags: pipe

I want to build a stand (like mic stand, telescope tripod etc) which can be used parallel with camera stand(tripod) or by attaching it to the camera stand. So I can hold/attach binocular/telescope/magnifier glasses over it and can concentrate on wiggle free photography.

Purpose of creating this stand is macro photography and tele photography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a gorilla grip stand a go. They seem to perform well and are rather small, they have the ability to adjust to uneven floors etc.